# difference between Joining with condition and joining with subquery (filter)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand difference between joining with a condition and joining with subquery.

In SQL Server,

```
CREATE TABLE #tab1
(audit_key int
,name varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(1,'Rich')
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(1,'Rodes')
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(2,'Rich')
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(2,'Rodes')
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(3,'Rich')
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(3,'Rodes')

SELECT a.audit_key,a.name,b.name 
FROM #tab1 a
JOIN #tab1 b ON b.name='Rodes' AND b.audit_key=2
WHERE a.name='Rich' AND a.audit_key=2

SELECT a.audit_key,a.name,b.name 
FROM #tab1 a
JOIN (SELECT audit_key,name FROM #tab1 WHERE audit_key=2 AND name='Rodes') b ON 1=1
WHERE a.name='Rich' AND a.audit_key=2

drop table #tab1
```

In above script, what happens in the first select?
Will it filter records based on b.name='Rodes' AND b.audit_key=2 first and then join that with 'tab1 a' records?

Is there a difference between 1st select and 2nd select?

How SQL Server treats these two selects in background?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the execution plan, they are treated exactly the same in the background. If you are not familiar with the execution plans, here is some resource:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

May be just me, but the way the first is written seems odd, I would usually write something like:

```
SELECT a.audit_key,a.name,b.name 
FROM #tab1 a
JOIN #tab1 b ON b.name=a.name AND b.audit_key=a.audit_key
WHERE a.name='Rich' AND a.audit_key=2
```

Because in yours, you are joining on everything, in effect making the same derived table, as you are specifying the criteria in the join. The above code matches on the two, and then the where specifies what it is you are looking for.

Comment: I know a bit about execution plans and in this case, both plans are showing 2 table scans and a nested loop(inner join) with query cost of 18%. Also, when b.audit_key=a.audit_key condition used, it will match all audit_keys first(1,2,3) and then filter on a.audit_key=2, at the end. However, I'm interested to  know the difference, when I exclusively filter it on audit_key.

Comment: So what is confusing you looking at the different execution plans, as that will tell you the differences.

Comment: I want to know, if SQL Server treats  `JOIN (SELECT audit_key,name FROM #tab1 WHERE audit_key=2 AND name='Rodes') b ON 1=1` and `JOIN #tab1 b ON b.name='Rodes' AND b.audit_key=2` same, or is there any difference

Comment: The execution plans are precisely the same, as mentioned, so the process that the query optimiser takes to get the results is exactly the same, what more detail do you want?